# Python with tcpdump in a subprocess: how to close subprocess properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, tcpdump

I have a Python script to capture network traffic with `tcpdump` in a `subprocess`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump', '-I', '-i', 'en1',
                  '-w', 'cap.pcap'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(10)
p.kill()
```

When this script completes its work, I'm trying to open output `.pcap` file in Wireshark and getting this **error:**

> "The capture file appears to have been cut short in the middle of a packet."

What solution could be applied for "proper" closing of `tcpdump`'s `subprocess`?

Comment: `p.wait()` should wait until the process has finished. I think then that the process is "closed"?

Comment: In my case it's "infinite" process (until user or timer not close it)

Comment: Are you using `p.kill()` in your program or are you interrupting by some other means?

Comment: I'm using `p.kill()` in my program after 10 seconds of capturing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `p.kill()`, you can use `p.send_signal(subprocess.signal.SIGTERM)` to send a terminate signal rather than a kill (`p.terminate()` does the same).

The [Popen docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) describe the `send_signal()` command.  The documentation on signals is a bit weak, but a dir(subprocess.signal) will list all the signals you may send to the process, but terminate should allow it some time to clean up.

Answer (score 2):

Found working solution:
I've changed `p.kill()` to `p.terminate()`.
After this change the `subprocess` is "properly" finished (output of `tcpdump` subprocess with statistics available in console) and output `.pcap` file not damaged.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem about closing `subprocess`es. This thread really helped, so thanks, especially to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3583715/rkh. My solution:

Before:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
message = output.stdout.read()
output.stdout.close()
```

After reading the Popen docs:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
message = output.stdout.read()
output.TerminateProcess()
```

For some reason, calling `output.kill()`, and/or `output.terminate()` or sending `output.send_signal(subprocess.signal.SIGTERM)` didn't work, but `output.TerminateProcess()` did.