# How to exit cleanly with tcpdump running in subprocess in sudo mode

Tags: python, subprocess, tcpdump

I am running `tcpdump` using the `subprocess` module in `python` to capture a trace of a website, using this piece of code:

```
import subprocess
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver

site = "check.torproject.org"

try:

        process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'tcpdump', '-l', '-i', 'eth0', '-w', 'trace.pcap'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        with TorBrowserDriver("/path/to/tor-browser_en-US/") as driver:
            driver.load_url("https://" + site, wait_on_page=20)

        process.send_signal(subprocess.signal.SIGTERM)

except OSError:
    print "OSError"
```

The code gives me an `OSError` and when I try to open the `pcap` file in `wireshark` I get the following error box:

`The capture file appears to have been cut short in the middle of a packet.`

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140000/python-with-tcpdump-in-a-subprocess-how-to-close-subprocess-properly) solution to the same issue, and have tried sending both a `SIGINT` and a `SIGTERM`, but I get the same truncated-packet message in each case along with an `OSError`. I have also tried using `process.terminate()` but that doesn't work either. Is there any way I could make `tcpdump` exit cleanly while running in `sudo` mode. Thanks!

Comment: Not an area I know much about, but there appear to be tools around to repair `pcap` files, e.g. `pcapfix`.

Comment: Not much detail about OSError? could you try `except OSError, e: print e`

Comment: @Kadir Its `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, I'll look into `pcapfix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the ***OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted*** suggest, killing the process is not permitted. Because you used **sudo**, killing the process should be instantiated **sudo** as well. Maybe you try this:

```
import subprocess
import os
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver

site = "check.torproject.org"

try:
    process = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'tcpdump', '-l', '-i', 'eth0', '-w', 'trace.pcap'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    with TorBrowserDriver("/path/to/tor-browser_en-US/") as driver:
        driver.load_url("https://" + site, wait_on_page=20)

    cmd = "sudo kill " + str(process.pid)
    os.system(cmd)
except OSError, e:
    print e
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Exits cleanly reporting the number of packets captured. And no truncated packets reported by `wireshark`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `tcpdump` needs su privileges you can simply run the script as su and check for it before you spawn tcpdump:

```
# Check we are running as root:
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    print('This script requires root privileges to capture packets. Try running this script as root.')
    raise SystemExit

# Start TCPDUMP
import subprocess, os
_process = subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump', '-nnvvv', '-s0', '-w', os.path.join('/tmp', 'output.pcap'), ])
```

This way you can run

```
_process.terminate()
```

or

```
_process.kill()
```

to send the proper signal to `tcpdump`